# CSS center align div on top of 100% width slideshow

Tags: html, css

I have the below slideshow which is 100% of the screen width.  I need to position the banner_slideshow_controls div on top of this in the middle.

I have tried setting the main container of the slideshow to relative and then setting the div to absolute but this will not sit in the middle unless I set a width and margin: 0 auto on the slideshow which I cannot do as I need it to be 100%.

Can anyone suggest a work around for this?

```
    <div id="banner_slideshow_container">
                    <div id="banner_slideshow">
                        <a href="about-us.php" style="background-image: URL(ui/banners/banner1.jpg)"></a>
                        <a href="about-us.php" style="background-image: URL(ui/banners/banner2.jpg)"></a>
                        <a href="about-us.php"  style="background-image: URL(ui/banners/banner3.jpg)"></a>
                        <a href="about-us.php" style="background-image: URL(ui/banners/banner4.jpg)"></a>
                        <a href="about-us.php" style="background-image: URL(ui/banners/banner5.jpg)"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="banner_slideshow_controls">
                        <div class="slideshow_caption">TEXT FOR BANNER</div>
                        <div class="slideshow_button">More Information</div>
                            <div id="prev" class="img_replace">Previous</div>
                            <div id="next" class="img_replace">Next</div>
                  </div>     
                </div>

#banner_slideshow_container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 366px;
    margin-top: 339px;
    background-color:#ccc;
}

#banner_slideshow {height:366px}

#banner_slideshow a{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:block;

}


#banner_slideshow_controls {
position:relative;
top:-100px;
margin: auto 0;
width:900px;
 z-index:10;
border:2px solid green

}
```

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to center horizontally, left and right margin has to be `auto`, so margin: 0 auto, or shorter `margin: auto` (because default `div` margin is 0)

Or if you want to use absolute position, add to `#banner_slider_container` `position: relative` and than you can position absolutely (if you don´t know container width, you can use `left: 50%; margin-left: -450px`)

Answer (score 0):

`margin: x y` is short hand for -

```
margin-top: x
margin-bottom: x
margin-right: y
margin-left: y
```

If I understood the requirement correctly -
set `margin : 0 auto` not the other way around on `#banner_slideshow_controls`

By doing that you set the left, right margin to 'auto' and top,bottom margin to 0 - which will place the div in the middle.